# How to do remote server/virtual server management job?

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I have recently learnt about the server management. While looking for freelance job, I have seen a post about managing 1200 servers. I got curious how a group of people can manage some thousands of servers. After visiting the service providers' site, like rack911.com , platinumservermanagement.com - I have found that they are charging only $19 to max $35 per server per month.

I am eager to know, how it is done, assuming that those server runs lot of virtual servers, serving as any cloud purpose, or as a web hosting server. 
How they manage all the servers, what tools or software they are using? Even need to implement security, lots of cron tasks, network and server uptime management etc.

How clients request tickets to the management company - I have seen froxlor, but not sure if everyone is using the same thing, or it is the exactly the thing needed for clients' ticketing and communication purposes.

Do server managers also need to have some high performance desktop/server at his work place - if yes, why they need to have a highly configured systems?

I am good at linux, unix and Windows server administration, but never had this server management, specially managing some thousands of servers, that's too for $19 to $35 charge per server per month. I am highly interested to learn about this server management job. looking for some good responses on how to initiate the management expertness - suggestion of learning path, tools to use, system setup recommendation are highly expected from experts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question is too broad and opinion based for server fault. Concepts like configuration management, IaaS, business processes, business models are complex concepts not tied to any specific tool or technology

Comment: As we say when you sign-up for this site "Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment." i.e. it's not for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The low cost managed server business model is based on a presumption that most of the customers would not need any changes most of the time. The basic installation is an automatic process if you have a virtual machine template ready. Then you just add services that the customer needs, which is again, nothing but running a script that installs the services. This all can be automated using PowerShell and only need very little human interaction if prepared properly.

Do not expect custom programming work to be done on low budged managed servers. They will only install and configure mail server, web server, CMS, FTP, database, ... things that can be (semi-)automatically installed and configured.